# Graph - just show last 12 months

Tags: reporting-services, graph

I have a line graph in my report.

My report has no parameters on it.

What I ideally want it to do is if I run the report today (May) it will only show me the last 12 months so May to May.

[image]

At the moment it is including April from last year as well, so would want that excluded. If I run it in two months time in July I would want it to only show July to July.

Hi,

The key here is the DatePaid field. This is the date that drives the graph.

The graph gets the Financial Year and Month from a date table.

The plots on the graph use an expression - 
[code="other"]=SUM(IIF(Fields!InvoicePaid_.Value = "Yes" And Fields!PaidTarget.Value = "InTarget",1, 0))/Count(IIF(Fields!InvoicePaid_.Value = "Yes", 1, Nothing))[/code]
This allows a % to be calculated on the graph series you see above, to just show invoices that have been paid and are in target.

The report uses TSQL and I'm wondering if there is a flag I can place against any invoice that was paid 12 months ago. And then via a filter remove them from the graph?

So today date is 02/06/2015. I would want to mark all invoices with a flag upto 01/06/14 so they all appear on the graph - but May and April 2014 would be excluded.

Then when I run the report next month say  - 7th of July 2015  - June 2014 will no longer appear on the graph but the 01/07/2014 and onwards would?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you need to paginate the graph, or just have the query bring back the last 12 months?

Comment: So write your SQL accordingly.

Comment: May to May is 13 months; June to May is 12 months

Comment: How would I write that in SQL? Plus this is in SSRS, so it's not TSQL but VBA is it not?

Raj don't know what you mean by paginate?

I just need the graph to pull back the last 12 months depending on what month you run it. So if I run it today it will show me May 2014 till May 2015. If I run it on the 1st of June it will run June 2014 till June 2015.

Comment: What is the data source and data set for this chart?

Comment: I've edited the post to include more information. Thanks